# How to create flask-sitemap for dynamic addresses?

Tags: python, flask, sitemap

I have the function for single post page with many queries etc. I want to attach @sitemap.register_generator but get error because arguments. How can I forse this function work?

```
# single post page
@views.route('/posts/<string:slug>-<int:id>')
def single_post_page(slug, id):
    post = Posts.query.get_or_404(id, slug)
    users = User.query.order_by(User.second_name.asc())
    side_posts = Posts.query.order_by(Posts.title.desc()).paginate(per_page=5, page=1, error_out=True)
    posts = Posts.query.order_by(Posts.title.asc()).paginate(per_page=10, page=1, error_out=True)
    page_title = post.title
    results = Posts.query.join(User).filter(User.id == Posts.publisher_id)
    cats = Category.query.order_by(Category.cat.asc())
    keyws = Keyword.query.order_by(Keyword.keyw.asc())
    no_tags = re.sub(pattern, '', post.content)
    cat_keyw_query = Posts.query \
        .join(post_category, post_category.c.posts_id == Posts.id) \
        .join(Category, post_category.c.cat_id == Category.id) \
        .filter(Category.id == post_category.c.cat_id) \
        .all()
    return render_template("blog/single_post.html", page_title=page_title, id=id, slug=slug, post=post,
                           results=results, users=users, posts=posts, side_posts=side_posts, timezone=timezone,
                           len=len, slugify=slugify, cats=cats, keyws=keyws, ck_query=cat_keyw_query, no_tags=no_tags)
```

sitemap function that I tried to attach

```
@sitemap.register_generator
def single_post_page(slug, id):
    post = Posts.query.get_or_404(id, slug)
    yield 'views.single_post_page', {}, datetime.datetime.now(), 'monthly', 0.7, slug, id
```

I want to avoid this error - single_post_page() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'slug' and 'id', but do not know how

Comment: found it 

@sitemap.register_generator
def all_posts():
    posts = Posts.query.all()
    for post in posts:
        yield 'views.single_post_page', {'id': post.id, 'slug': post.slug}, datetime.datetime.now(), 'monthly', 0.7

Comment: That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 1):

found it

```
@sitemap.register_generator
def all_posts():
    posts = Posts.query.all()
    for post in posts:
        yield 'views.single_post_page', {'id': post.id, 'slug': post.slug}, datetime.datetime.now(), 'monthly', 0.7
```